# Using Roboto in offline app

Tags: cordova, angular, angular-material2, roboto

I have a Cordova/Angular2 app, based on `angular-cli`, also using Material Design. I note that when I build I get files in my `dist` directory such as

```
roboto-v15-latin-regular.eot  
roboto-v15-latin-regular.svg  
roboto-v15-latin-regular.ttf  
roboto-v15-latin-regular.woff  
roboto-v15-latin-regular.woff2
```

although frankly I have no idea who is responsible for bringing these in. The problem is that even thought I have `body { font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; }` in my CSS, Roboto is not being applied and I get the plain old sans-serif font. I suspect that the necessary `@font-face` declarations may need to be brought in from somewhere, but I have no idea from where.

My question is: is there a magic CSS file somewhere with the appropriate `@font-face` definitions in it that I can `@import` from `app/styles.css`, for example?

Also, the fonts in the distribution seem to only be for regular weights. Since I don't know who is responsible for these fonts being included in the build in the first place, I also am puzzled about how I could bring in other versions of Roboto with different weights if I wanted to.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378320/how-to-include-roboto-font-in-webpack-build-for-material-ui) but it seems overly complex and possibly out-of-date.