# Fonts in googleapi links

Tags: google-font-api

Rather than using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">`, is it possible to get the CSS style and place it in a CSS file?

I am asking because, if Google changes their above Googleapi link and I forgot to update he link on my site, it will affect some of the fonts I used on my website.

Comment: They wouldn't change the link, much less without a lot of warnings/notices.

Comment: Take a look at this answer on how to create a CSS file from the font. It looks like a bit of a 'hack' but written by an SO veteran (& it's even covering 'Roboto') _ Hope it helps : ) >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913349/3711083