Roboto font isn't rendering in Chrome
I'm having a problem with Roboto font in Chrome. It is not rendered on websites using it.
I've checked some text elements, deleted Roboto from the "font-family" property and it rendered other sans-serif font way closer to Robotosans-serif value. I tried to check which font is replacing Roboto with WhatFont extension - but it doesn't show me any issuedescription from WhatFont. I've deleted all Roboto fonts from my machine, reopen Chrome, restart the PC - no difference. I've tried with Edge - same issue, though no issue with Brave and Firefox.

Your browser doesn't look for fonts on your machine but fonts that are included in the page itself. The font needs to be 'pulled in' from the font source or installed on the web server and pulled from there.
The solution was already given on this site, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178867/how-can-i-use-googles-roboto-font-on-a-website

If it works in brave (also blink engine) and firefox it could be related to some blocking addon (like a adblocker) preventing to load fonts from google. So you might check your extensions and deactivate some. Can you see any reports in the console? (e.g 404 font not loaded, connection rejected etc)

@herrstrietzel I tried with all extensions turned off - no success. I've checked the console for errors,, but most responds were 200, couple 304 and nothing related to font issue.  I read that the problem could be in chrome://flags/Accelerated 2D canvas so I changed the settings but no success. I also checked in Chrome settings/Appearance/Customize fonts - configuration is the same as in Brave.
